# Liberar memoria al volver en UINavigationController

Tags: swift, ram

Estoy construyendo una aplicación en swift 4.1 sin utilizar el storyboard. Básicamente en el appdelagate hago creo una instancia de mi controlador principal **mainVC** y lo agrego al root de mi navigation controller

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    //inicializar la aplicación
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

    let mainVC = MainVC()
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainVC)

    navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: true)
    window?.rootViewController = navigationController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

Dentro del mainVC tengo una botón que invoca a un siguiente cotrolador de vista **categoriesVC** :

```
 @objc func goToCategories(){
    let categoriesVC = CategoriesVC()
    categoriesVC.view.backgroundColor = .cyan
    categoriesVC.title = "Categorías"
    categoriesVC.currentRegion = currentRegion

    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    navigationController?.pushViewController(categoriesVC, animated: true)
}
```

Y su vez dentro del controlador categoriesCV que contiene un tableView, invoco un siguiente controlador que también contiene un datatable **subCategoriesVC**.

Estoy observando que cuando regreso al primer view **categoriesCV** y selecciono la misma opción para ir al segundo controlador **subCategoriesVC** el uso de la ram aumenta. Cada que realizo esta acción de volver atrás y después ir para adelante la RAM aumenta en 5 o 6 MB.

Yo estoy suponiendo que se crean nuevas instancias de los controladores que se van a presentar cada vez y que nunca se liberan de la memoria. ¿Hay alguna manera de liberar las vistas que se cargaron o decirle al navigation controller que cuando regrese elimine las instancias creadas de las vistas que cargó?

Comment: Sí, se crean nuevas instancias siempre, es lo que se espera. No creo que sea un problema el aumento de la memoria, se va liberando según se requiera.

Comment: He encontrado que en el push and prop de los primeros dos view controllers no sucede esto, la memoria RAM permanece estable. Es hasta la tercer vista que contiene imágenes donde el aumneto de RAM permanece y aumente en cada push and prop.

Comment: Como comento Vertig0 es un comportamiento normal y si estas cargando imagenes es algo comun, te recomiendo buscar retain cylces y usar propiedades weak en donde sea conveniente

Comment: Puedes leer esta pregunta, es justamente tu caso. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45601121/best-way-to-deinit-initial-view-controller